# Brouwer's fixed point theorem

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

Is the statement is true or false, please explain the reason 
Every continuous map $f \colon S^1 \to S^1$ has a fixed point where $S^1$ is a unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$ follows from Brouwer's fixed point theorem.

Comment: Welcome to math.se! As in TeX you can use $ for formatting of mathematics.

Comment: It doesn't. Consider rotating the circle by 45 degrees for example

Comment: If this is not the systematic outsourcing of one's homework, I don't know what is.

Answer (score 1):

Brouwer talks about the compact disk. You're asking about the boundary of the disk. Imagine the disk as a basin of water, where the continuous function is "swirl around the centre". Then Brouwer guarantees a fixed-point across the entire basin (here, the centre is fixed), but not the edge.